# When to close Connection, Statement, PreparedStatement and ResultSet in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, resultset

Few questions on JDBC coding:

1. For a single client application, do we need a Connection pool?
2. Is it a good idea to create a `Connection` at the beginning and keep it alive without close it until application exit? Why?
3. `PreparedStatement` is associated with `Connection`, if my connection is not closed after each query, why not keep the `PreparedStatement` alive and reuse it in other methods?
4. if we create `PreparedStatement` each query, does the database knows it is the same `PreparedStatement` and ignore unnecessary actions after the first time?
5. `PreparedStatement` is not create once and reuse many times statement? If yes, why need to close it each time?

I know the call to `close()` will release the resource. But If we know we are going to use it later, why release it and then request it again later?

How about a multi-client application? We need a connection pool and so we need to create and close Connection, `Statement`, and `PreparedStatement` each time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507440/must-jdbc-resultsets-and-statements-be-closed-separately-although-the-connection

Answer (score 17):

Personally I'd use a pool as this will take care of all of the resource management for you. If your connection requirements change then you can easily modify the pool configuration.  With a pool in place you can open/close connections and prepared statements according to best-practice and leave the resource management to the pool.

Typically, when using a pool:

- closing a connection will actually just return it to the pool
- the act of preparing a statement will either retrieve a previously prepared statement from the Connection's statement cache, or if one is not available, create a new statement and cache it for later use.
- the act of closing a PreparedStatement will actually just return it to the connection's statement cache.

Furthermore - depending on the pool implementation - it may be able to notify you when there are resource leaks making it easier to identify these sorts of problems in your code.

Take a look at the source of an example implementation like [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) - it's quite interesting to see how they work.

Comment: Don't trust your pool: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507440/must-jdbc-resultsets-and-statements-be-closed-separately-although-the-connection

Comment: @teabot I close all objects including Connection after each query execution. Is it better to open and close a Connection for each request instead of each statement?I mean, Statements and ResultSets are closed per using but connection is one for all of them per request (opens in start of request and closes at the end of last query execution)

Comment: @teabot can you update the best practices link, it 404

Answer (score 4):

**1.** Even if you have a single client, a connection pool may still be beneficial. Connecting to the database may take a significant time so doing it very often may slow down your application with slow network requests. Moreover as @teabot explains, a pool may help identifying if any connection is not being closed.

**2.** It is not a good idea to open a connection and leave it open forever for two reasons. First the connection may die if there is a temporary network interruption. The longer it is open the more likely that it is dead when required. Second, a failed transaction may leave the connection in a state not suitable for continuing operation. The best is usually to open a few connections, reuse them for five or ten minutes, then recycle them.

**3.** Depending on the database and the driver, the connection may have a prepared statement cache. Even if using a different connection, the RDBMS usually caches statements that are exactly the same including it parameters. Therefore SELECT * FROM table WHERE value=? as a prepared statement will be cached across connections, but if you specify the parameter value like SELECT * FROM table WHERE value='your_data' then probably it won't be cached server side.

**4.** As explained in 3, depends on the RDBMS implementation, do a benchmark.

**5.** There is no need to close and prepare again a statement which is going to be reused with different parameters. Just set again the parameters and execute.

For multiple clients, the database will always have a concurrent connection limit which is not usually any big number. If all the clients go through a webapp then a pool like DBCP is all right. But obviously it's undesirable to create a pool for each client with several connections open permanently.