# Can I keep one jdbc connection for the whole time

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection

My Java App has a lot of queries ( ~1000 queries/each button). Can I open JDBC connection when my app is launched and keep it instead of opening a connection every single time the button pressed and closing it after 1k queries? I understand that it is  possible, but **would it be better or no? Can it be lost somehow?** I use free mysql hosting that's why every time I open/close a new one it takes a lot of time.

Comment: You might find a little bit of useful information in https://stackoverflow.com/q/7280825/924 the general advice seems to be to use a Connection Pool instead of a single connection.

Comment: *"Can it be lost somehow?"* Yes. If server is rebooted. If you lose connectivity. If you don't use it for a while, server may time it out and discard it.

Comment: Adding to @BrandonHaugen comment, you can have a pool with max idle/active connection set to 1. This way you will have the best of both the worlds.

Comment: In this case is that possible use procedures on Database instead? You can call the function with the queries and part of your logic is exec on DB a way more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It can be closed by the server any time, typically on an idle timeout. You should get a new connection per transaction, and you should mitigate the ill-effects of that by using a connection pool like Apache DBCP.

Comment: Relevant meta post: [Answering a question, then closing it as duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286072/answering-a-question-then-closing-it-as-duplicate)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels This happens to me a lot somehow.

Comment: It's happened to me too at times. Usually I delete the answer and post a comment, or make the answer a community wiki

Comment: Funny, it's my up-vote too, since it was a lot better answer than Luis's

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I just read the meta post, and many of the attitudes expressed there seem to me to be totally bizarre. The question about whether anybody with enough reputation to close-hammer really needs to game the system is about the only sensible thing there..

Comment: Dunno, it's an odd predicament, and so I looked up the only meta reference I could find.