# Resultset is empty when I close preparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I have such a method:

```
private static ResultSet select (Connection connection, String query) {
        PreparedStatement selectQuery = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try {
            selectQuery = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            resultSet = selectQuery.executeQuery();
            selectQuery.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return resultSet;
    }
```

The thing is that the resultSet is always empty when I close the preparedStatement. 
If I comment out the line with clothing preparedStatement `//selectQuery.close();` everything is fine. 
I close it **after** assigning value to the resultSet. So why it's empty?

Comment: probably because it gets closed by the query close. You should not return ResultSet, use them "in place" and dispose of them

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039419/when-to-close-connection-statement-preparedstatement-and-resultset-in-jdbc?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ResultSet` is associated with an executed `Statement`. Close the statement and the resultset, with any data in it is cleared.

You need to process the resultset before you close the statement, so your approach will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Because the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close--) says so:

> Note: When a `Statement` object is closed, its current `ResultSet object`, if one exists, is also closed.

Rationale: The stated behavior of `Statement.close()` is to release all resources.  One of those resources is the server-side cursor for reading the results.  But if you release that, then the `ResultSet` has nothing to pull data from.

I'm curious how you are determining that the (closed) `ResultSet` is "empty".  It looks like all operations on a closed `ResultSet` (apart from `close()`) ought to throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You have not to close the statement before having retrieved the data of the resultset otherwise these may be not accessible.
When you call this method, its ResultSet objects are closed.

So, only when you are finished using a Statement, call the `Statement.close()` method.

The close should be performed in a finally statement.
In this way you are ensure that you don't worry to wonder when close it.

With your actual code :

```
private static ResultSet select (Connection connection, String query) {
        PreparedStatement selectQuery = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try {
            selectQuery = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            resultSet = selectQuery.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        finally {
           if (selectQuery != null) { selectQuery.close(); }
        }
        return resultSet;
    }    
}
```

A better alternative is using a try-with-resources statement :

```
try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate through the ResultSet. You have an high level example right here:

```
try{ 
  // execute the query
  ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

  // iterate through the result set
  while (rs.next())
  {
    // Replace with your data
    int id = rs.getInt("id");
    String name = rs.getString("name");

    // do stuff with the result set, add to a List of objects (for example)
  }
  selectQuery.close();
}catch(SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
}
```